# @Synthesize by default problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Knowing that from Xcode4 and LLVM 2.0 there is the new feature "@syntesize by default"

I tried the following code:

```
@interface PDFPage : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic,assign) int page;

@end

@implementation PDFPage

-(void)dealloc
{
    [self.name release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I assumed that @synthesize was no longer necessary but the compiler (Apple LLVM 2.1) give me  a warning like 'warning: property 'page' requires method 'page' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation'

What else I need to do to enable @synthesize by default ? (I also tried the flags -Xclang -fobjc-nonfragile-abi2 but they are not recognized).

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple removed the automatic `@synthesize` feature from the non-fragile ABI because of issues it was causing or uncertainties the compiler had when trying to autosynthesize properties. See [this blog post](http://www.mcubedsw.com/blog/index.php/site/comments/new_objective-c_features/) for more information about it.

Answer (score 2):

`@synthesize` is necessary, what is no longer necessary is a separate ivar declaration.  At one point it was planned that @synthesize would be automatic but there were problems so that plan did not materialize.

Answer (score 2):

Revisiting this answer, the current version of the LLVM compiler allows implicit synthesis. However, with the current compiler (late-2012) a scalar property declaration requires you to manually declare the property in a `@synthesize` statement if you want to specify an ivar name. Dunno why they make the distinction.

There is one other time that you need to manually `@synthesize` a property, and that's when it's declared in a category that you've imported into your source.

If you want to force explicit synthesis, there is a compiler flag: `CLANG_WARN_OBJC_MISSING_PROPERTY_SYNTHESIS` that won't stop the implicit synthesis from taking place, but will warn you about it if you want to enforce backwards compatibility.